# Storage Client Library 2.0 - Why is the API not as intuitive to use as 1.7?

Tags: c#, .net, api-design, azure

I am migrating to using the new Storage Client Library for my Azure Table Storage.

**Querying with the previous *Storage Client Library 1.7* namespace:**

```
var orders = serviceContext
                 .CreateQuery<Order>(tableName)
                 .AsTableServiceQuery<Order>()
                 .Where(e => e.PartitionKey == partitionKey && e.RowKey == rowKey)
```

**Querying with the new *Storage Client Library 2.0* classes:**

```
string partitionKeyFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey);
string rowKeyFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, rowKey);
string combinedFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(partitionKeyFilter, TableOperators.And, rowKeyFilter);

var query = new TableQuery<Order>().Where(combinedFilter);
var orders = table.ExecuteQuery<Order>(query);
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but 1.7 is cleaner, uses strongly-typed entities, implements the IQueryable interface and utilizes the full power of LINQ.  Version 2.0 makes me feel like I'm working with ADO.NET Datasets again.

Am I completely missing the plot here?  I understand that there have been major performance improvements, but version 2.0 feels like a downgrade of an API.

Why isn't there a `IQueryable<T>` interface for 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked the same question on Stackoverflow:

[Storage Client Library 2.0 - Why is the API not as intuitive to use as 1.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097902/storage-client-library-2-0-why-is-the-api-not-as-intuitive-to-use-as-1-7)

See the above link for answer.